# Iterating over groups in several DataFrames when groups may absent

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following problem. I have a DataFrame that lists items. Each item has multi-value properties A and B with zero or more values per item. The properties are stored in own DataFrame instances. For each item I want to get a set of all values both for A and B and perform some operation on both of these sets including the case when any of the sets is empty.

My initial solution was to group properties by items, then iterate over items and for each item use get_group to get its values both for A and B and perform the operation on these groups. This works in the following case:

```
# A sample toy operation. One should assume that my_operation
# takes array-like arguments that can be Python lists, 
# pandas.Series etc.  
def my_operation(array_a, array_b):
    return len(array_a) - len(array_b)

def example1():
    items = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['i1', 'i2', 'i3']})
    items_a = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['i1', 'i1', 'i2', 'i3'], 'A': [1, 2, 3, 0]})
    items_b = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['i1', 'i2', 'i2', 'i3'], 'B': [-1, 4, 5, 6]})

    grouped_a = items_a.groupby('Item')
    grouped_b = items_b.groupby('Item')
    for row in items.itertuples():
        a = grouped_a.get_group(row.Item)['A']
        b = grouped_b.get_group(row.Item)['B']
        print(row.Item, my_operation(a, b))

example1()
```

which prints expected:

```
i1 1
i2 -1
i3 0
```

However, this does not work when some of the items have zero values. For example, the following generate the KeyError:

```
def my_operation(array_a, array_b):
    return len(array_a) - len(array_b)

def example2():
    items = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4']})
    items_a = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['i1', 'i1', 'i2'], 'A': [1, 2, 3]})
    items_b = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['i2', 'i2', 'i3'], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})

    grouped_a = items_a.groupby('Item')
    grouped_b = items_b.groupby('Item')
    for row in items.itertuples():
        a = grouped_a.get_group(row.Item)['A']
        b = grouped_b.get_group(row.Item)['B']
        print(row.Item, my_operation(a, b))

example2()
```

I can fix that by checking before calling the get_group that the group exists and use an empty DataFrame if not, but it seems rather heavy and probably indicates that I missed some simpler solution. So what it can be?

EDIT: in the real problem the operation on sets is a complex python code that does not accept NaN values. The case when both sets are empty are rather common and must be properly dealt with.

EDIT 2: the expected answer for the toy example above should be

```
i1 2
i2 -1
i3 -1
i4 0
```

EDIT 3: I rewrote the sample code to emphasize that the set operation is a generic Python function that takes array-like objects representing the sets of values.

Comment: Can you provide some data that has the behavior as you described in your EDIT section?

Comment: In the real problem each item is an a video frame and some of its properties. The values are the sets of detected and expected boxes of objects in the frame. The operation evaluates how good is a match between those sets.

Comment: Deleted my answer :P Don't what your "real" problem means. Give your "real" problem in the problem definition then.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do a `groupby` with some function to make a collection as argument to `apply()`

```
def my_grouping(df, label, on):
    return df.groupby(on)[label].apply(list)
```

to generate the list-likes for each group.

```
def my_operation(array_a, array_b):
    try:
        len_a = len(array_a)
    except TypeError:
        len_a = 0

    try:
        len_b = len(array_b)
    except TypeError:
        len_b = 0
    return len_a - len_b
```

Your `my_operation` needed something to handle empty items

```
def aggregate(df1, df2, items, label1='A', label2='B', on='Item'):
    count1 = my_grouping(df1, label1, on)
    count2 = my_grouping(df2, label2, on)
#     print(count1, count2)
    merged = pd.DataFrame({label1: count1, label2: count2})
#     print(merged)
    result_data = ((idx, my_operation(a, b)) for idx, a, b in merged.itertuples())
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_data).rename(columns={0: 'Item', 1:'value'}).set_index('Item')
    return result_df.reindex(items).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

the `aggregate` function call the `my_grouping`, concatenates the 2 arrays, call `my_operation` on each of the elements, and returns a `DataFrame` with the results. The last line adds the missing items, and fills them with 0's

This can be called like this:

```
def example2():
    all_items = ['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4']
    items_a = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['i1', 'i1', 'i2'], 'A': [1, 2, 3]})
    items_b = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['i2', 'i2', 'i3'], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
    return (aggregate(items_a, items_b, all_items))
```

> ```
> print(example2())
> ```

```
Item    value
i1  2
i2  -1
i3  -1
i4  0
```

If your real operation is just the difference in length, then this small function performs the exact same work, which, if you would want, can be done in 1 line

```
def aggregate2(df1, df2, items, label1='A', label2='B', on='Item'):  
    count1 = df1.groupby(on)[label1].count()
    count2 = df2.groupby(on)[label2].count()
    diff = count1 - count2
    return result_df.reindex(items).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: reindex trick is nice :) The code essentially replaces 1:N table with 1:1 one containing lists of values. But why do not you use reindex on the result of my_grouping to avoid special-casing zero-length values like in `my_grouping(df1, label1, on).reindex(items, fill_value=[])`? Then one can just join items with grouped and reindexed df1 and df2 and just apply the operation to the rows of the resulting table.

Comment: Where you do the reindex is of little importance. The rest of the code can stay the same. Invoking the DataFrame constructor with the dict of Series is essentially a join

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used pandas before, but if you want to double check the Item exists in the `items` dataframe, can't you do a check before you group?

```
def example2():
    items = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4']})
    items_a = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['i1', 'i1', 'i2'], 'A': [1, 2, 3]})
    items_b = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['i2', 'i2', 'i3'], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})

    grouped_a = items_a.groupby('Item')
    grouped_b = items_b.groupby('Item')
    for row in items.itertuples():
        a = []  # so that len(a) returns 0 if get_group() doesn't trigger
        b = []  # so that len(b) returns 0 if get_group() doesn't trigger
        if row.Item in items_a['Item'].values:
            a = grouped_a.get_group(row.Item)
        if row.Item in items_b['Item'].values:
            b = grouped_b.get_group(row.Item)
        print(row.Item, len(a) - len(b))
```

It's probably not the most elegant solution, or may even be a frowned upon practice (since I'm essentially redefining `a`/`b` to a different type).  But here's what I got as a result:

```
i1 2
i2 -1
i3 -1
i4 0
```

I'm not sure if this is your expected results though as you did not provide it in your OP.

Edit: An alternative that does the same way but less verbose is define a function before hand:

```
def example2():
    items = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4']})
    items_a = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['i1', 'i1', 'i2'], 'A': [1, 2, 3]})
    items_b = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['i2', 'i2', 'i3'], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})

    item_key = 'Item'
    get_group = lambda item, df, key: df.groupby(key).get_group(item) if item in df[key].values else []
    for row in items.itertuples():
        a = get_group(row.Item, items_a, item_key)
        b = get_group(row.Item, items_b, item_key)
        print(row.Item, len(a) - len(b))
```

It takes up less lines, but now it's less readable.

Comment: This is expected result and this is roughly what I was planing to do as I indicated in the question. I thought I missed some good trick to deal with multi-valued properties.

Comment: Ah I see, you're asking if there's a better way to implement this.  My bad, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: If you feel the code is ugly you can define a lambda function before you the loop: `get_group = lambda group, item, df : group.get_group(item) if item in df['Item'].values else []`, and then just do `a = get_group(grouped_a, row.Item, items_a)` in the iteration (and same for b).  It's the same thing but will take up less lines.  The caveat is that the code is now less readable.

Comment: Initially I was planning to empty DataFrame for the case when group does not exists, but your suggestions about using [] is really makes things simpler. My operation on sets treats empty list just as well as empty DataFrame :)